# instagram.com/{USER_NAME}/?__a=1 no longer works without authentication?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I've been working on a webapp for the past couple months that displays info about different restaurants in my city, and I've been using  [https://www.instagram.com/{USER_NAME}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7BUSER_NAME%7D/?__a=1) to get each profile picture from every restaurant. There haven't been any problem with this, until maybe like 30-40 minutes ago I had been getting the next error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

It seemed weird to me beacuse I didn't change anything in my api, so after a little bit of research, I realized that if I go to this route to get a json response, it only works if I'm logged in ,which it wasn't needed before.

Is there any workaround this? Like it seems weird to me because my api has been working fine for the past couple months until like half and hour ago when I began to get undefined instead of the profile picture of each restaurant.

Comment: Are you getting any data back at all for any restaurants? I am getting public data back for a public account I tested when using that URL. Maybe one of the restaurants made their account private and it's failing due to that.

Comment: I can confirm.
`?__a=1` used to work without being authenticated, and it stopped working 2 days ago.

Also looking for a workaround. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you request that data? Because going directly to the url in your browser, will get you back the data if you are logged in, otherwise if you are not logged in, it wil redirecty you to the log in page.

As a workaround, the only thing that I could think of, was going to each one of these restaurants url using `?__=1` and copying their link for each profile picture, and then, saving that link in my database. Yeah, kind of a stupid solution, but fortunately that's the only thing I need from each instagram page.

Comment: i saw this too, any idea why is not showing business_email key? how to get that key? @Fabian